# Get Request IP in Jersey Request Event Listener

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have the following RequestEventListener in Jersey 2.26:

```
package com.myapp.webservice;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEvent;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

public class RequestEventListener implements org.glassfish.jersey.server.monitoring.RequestEventListener {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestEventListener.class);
    private final long startTime;

    @Context
    private javax.inject.Provider<Request> request;

    RequestEventListener() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        switch(requestEvent.getType()) {
            case RESOURCE_METHOD_START:
                try {
                    logger.info("HTTPRequest {} /{} {}", requestEvent.getContainerRequest().getMethod(), requestEvent.getContainerRequest().getUriInfo().getPath(), request.get().getRemoteAddr());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Exception {}", e);
                }
                break;

            case FINISHED:
                logger.info("HTTPResponse {} /{} {}", requestEvent.getContainerResponse().getLength(), requestEvent.getContainerRequest().getUriInfo().getPath(), System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to inject the grizzly http Request object, which works like that when i use a RequestFilter instead an EventListener. But i get NullPointerException regarding the `request` object.

Is it possible to get the request's IP address in that (or any other) way inside an RequestEventListener?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're just instantiating it. You can't expect for it to be injected this way. What you can do is inject it (the `Provider<Request>` into the `ApplicationEventListener` and pass it the request listener constructor. Or you could inject the `ServiceLocator` (`InjectionManager` for 2.26+) into the `ApplicationEventListener` and call `locator.inject(requestListener)`. That would explicitly inject the request listener.